# Redirect to profile page after authentication in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

When a user logs in I want them to be redirected to their profile page instead of homepage. I have a method in another controller that gets a user profile. Not sure what I need to do since the user profile takes a username variable but when user logs in I'm only asking for email and password.

My route file, but the following method is in a different controller from the authentication controller.

```
Route::get('/user/{username}', [
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@getProfile',
    'as' => 'profile.index',
    'middleware' => ['auth'],
    ]);
```

My following method is in my authentication controller.

```
public function postSignin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',

        ]);

    if (!Auth::attempt($request->only(['email', 'password']),      $request->has('remember'))) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('info' , 'Could not sign you in with that info.');
    }

        $user= User::where('username', $username)->first();
        return redirect()->route('profile.index')
        ->with('info', 'You are now signed in.')
        ->with('user', $user);
     }
```

The following is in my profile controller..

```
public function getProfile($username)
{
    $user= User::where('username', $username)->first();

    if (!$user){
        abort(404);
    }
    return view('profile.index')
        ->with('user', $user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To correctly build the route, you need to pass the username here:

```
$user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
    return redirect()->route('profile.index', ['username' => $user->username])
    ->with('info', 'You are now signed in.')
    ->with('user', $user);
```

Comment: I tried that but I get username is undefined. Don't know how I can do this when I'm only passing in email and password

Comment: This is just an example, mate, I don't know your database structure, but you should, the fact is that you need to pass something to that route to build it correctly

Comment: Yes in my database my username field is "username" but I get ...Missing required parameters for [Route: profile.index] [URI: user/{username}].

Answer (score 0):

Get the username from the email provided and pass the `$username` variable to route:

```
public function postSignin(Request $request)
{ 
      if (!Auth::attempt($request->only(['email', 'password']),$request->has('remember'))) 
      {
           return redirect()->back()->with('info' , 'Could not sign you in with that info.');
      }

   $username=User::where(['email'=>$request->email])->first()->username;
   return redirect()->route('profile.index')->with('username', $username);
}
```

Comment: When I tried that I got an error:  Missing required parameters for [Route: profile.index] [URI: user/{username}].

Comment: @Slillz `return redirect('user/{$username}');`

Comment: They gave me: NotFoundHttpException in Application.php line 902:

Answer (score -1):

You can use as like below.

```
  if (!Auth::attempt($request->only(['email', 'password']),      $request->has('remember'))) {
    return redirect('profile.index')->with('info' , 'Could not sign you in with that info.');
```